# why is my flutter and dart plug in not installed?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I already did installed it but when I use flutter doctor it says that dart in not installed/flutter is not installed. how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow official step by step procedure to install flutter

[Install flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows)

Answer (score 0):

check your flutter path and setup.

[image]

Go to Setting and check your path.and after this apply this.